# Can there be a special Show instance for a tuple?

Tags: haskell

I am working with so-called tokens which are tuples with a string and a tag that I wish I could render on the screen in the following format: `[TAG: VALUE]` I cannot do that because I am not doing something right. Here is the setup:

```
type Token value tag = ([value], tag)
data Tag = Whitespace | Alpha | Digit | Punctuation | Terminal
instance Show Tag where
    show Alpha = "A"
    show Whitespace = "W"
    show Digit = "D"
    show Punctuation = "P"
    show Terminal = "|"
type TextToken = Token Char Tag    
instance Show TextToken where
    show (values, tag) = "[" ++ show tag ++ ": " ++ values ++ "]"
```

Which crashes at compiling:

```
Illegal instance declaration for `Show TextToken'
  (All instance types must be of the form (T t1 ... tn)
   where T is not a synonym.
   Use -XTypeSynonymInstances if you want to disable this.)
In the instance declaration for `Show TextToken'
```

Then I tried replacing the instance with the following:

```
instance Show ([Char], Tag) where
   show (values, tag) = "[" ++ show tag ++ ": " ++ values ++ "]"
```

And got the same problem again:

```
Illegal instance declaration for `Show ([Char], Tag)'
  (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
   where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
   and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
   Use -XFlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
In the instance declaration for `Show ([Char], Tag)'
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: As a side note, you might take a look a the [GHC compiler flags reference](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/flag-reference.html) if you're not familiar with that already.

Comment: A recommendation from more experienced Haskell programmers is to avoid overriding the default `Show` instance for things. `show` is one of the staple tools for debugging: you should be able to `show` a data structure and then copy and paste it into `ghci` for further debugging. You'll notice that all of the standard libraries follow this format. If you want pretty-printing, it is a better idea to define your own function for that.

Answer (score 10):

You'll want to use a newtype

```
newtype Tag a b = Tag (a, b)

instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (Tag a b) where
  show (Tag (a, b)) = "[" ++ show a ++ ": " ++ show b ++ "]"
```

You're running into several instance resolution quibbles all at once.

1. Without the `{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}` pragma, you cannot use `type` synonyms in instance definitions... even if they're perfectly clear. Enabling it is fine, it's simply not Haskell 98.
2. When using complex, nested, or multiparameter types in instance definitions, you frequently run afoul of the overly restrictive Haskell 98 instance definition. In many cases this is fine, so enabling the `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}` pragma will allow these OK opportunities.
3. Finally, dangerously, there's *already* a `Show` instance for `([Char], Tag)`, the polymorphic one `instance Show (a, b)` with `a ~ [Char]` and `b ~ Tag`. This means you'll run afoul of the `OverlappingInstances` warning.

You can disable this by telling GHC to allow `OverlappingInstances` using another pragma `{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}` but since it can cause very strange runtime behavior for both yourself and others who use your code, its use is highly discouraged.

Generally, if you're trying to "specialize" an instance declaration to a particular type, you need the general case to not exist.

```
newtype Tup a b = Tup (a, b)

instance Show (Tup Int Int) where
  show (Tup tup) = show tup

instance Show (Tup String Int) where
  show (Tup (s, int)) = s ++ ": " ++ show int

>>> show ("foo", 3)
foo: 3
>>> show (2, 3)
(2, 3)
>>> show ("foo", "bar")
No instance for...
```

Answer (score 3):

**The thing that you really need to decide** is if you want different instances for different sorts of `Token`. If you do, then use a `newtype` (or compiler option, as some suggest). If you don't, then make `Token` a `data` and define your instance on the generic `Token` type.

To make a `newtype` wrapper:

```
newtype TextToken = TextToken (Token Char Tag)
```

then declaring the `Show` instance for the wrapper:

```
instance Show TextToken where
```

In your case I'd still recommend changing

```
type Token value tag = ([value], tag)
```

to

```
data Token value tag = Token [value] tag
```

because you have a record type anyway, so you might as well make it explicit.